# Unity 3D build hangs in Jenkins (also using Mercurial)

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, unity-game-engine, continuous-integration

I'm currently trying to turn one of my Windows 7 machine into a continuous integration server that builds Unity 3D projects from several Mercurial repositories.  For testing purposes, I chose this fairly minimal project that has one scene, one build script, one .hgignore file, and a bunch of README.txt files so I can commit the folders into Mercurial.  Naturally for this purpose, I'm using the Unity3dBuilder, Mercurial, and Redmine plugins in Jenkins.  Here is the console output that I get:

```
$ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" clone --noupdate C:\repo\TemplateUnityProject.hg C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\hgcache\F3BC0D0C62E81590DAC468D0CD39E7E3EEF2EA34
Master cache lock released.
$ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" clone --noupdate C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\hgcache\F3BC0D0C62E81590DAC468D0CD39E7E3EEF2EA34 "C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\jobs\Template Unity Project\workspace"
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" --config extensions.relink= relink C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\hgcache\F3BC0D0C62E81590DAC468D0CD39E7E3EEF2EA34
relinking C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\hgcache\F3BC0D0C62E81590DAC468D0CD39E7E3EEF2EA34\.hg/store to C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\jobs\Template Unity Project\workspace\.hg/store
tip has 89 files, estimated total number of files: 133
collected 105 candidate storage files
pruned down to 0 probably relinkable files
relinked 0 files (0 bytes reclaimed)
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" update --rev default
89 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" log --rev . --template {node}
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" log --rev . --template {rev}
WARN: Revision data for previous build unavailable; unable to determine change log
Piping unity Editor.log from C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -projectPath "C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.568-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\jobs\Template Unity Project\workspace" -quiet -bashmode -executeMethod OmiyaGamesBuildScript.BuildAllPlatforms

(many lines later...)

Updating Assets/Prefabs/README.txt - GUID: ccf982a6fa129ff4a8e9531a991ff6e7...
 done. [Time: 22.739634 ms] 
Updating Assets/Models/README.txt - GUID: e0c2cd9840708ee4aaa37cb896c50e40...
 done. [Time: 22.553606 ms] 
System memory in use before: 15.4 MB.
Unloading 16 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)
System memory in use after: 13.4 MB.

Unloading 1 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 292.
Total: 15.136999 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.071680 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.017635 ms MarkObjects: 1.146880 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.029582 ms)


----- Total AssetImport time: 6.310404s, AssetImport time: 6.069061s, Asset hashing: 0.017528s [9.1 KB, 0.505129 mb/s]

Updating ProjectSettings/GraphicsSettings.asset - GUID: 00000000000000006100000000000000...
 done. [Time: 15.341799 ms] 

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.076351s, AssetImport time: 0.047076s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.005972 seconds (Nothing changed)
Determining assets that need to be reimported for target platform ... 0.021060 seconds.

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.020425s, AssetImport time: 0.000001s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

(Then it hangs forever...)
```

It seems that, for whatever reason, the project just hangs forever after importing every assets.  Any idea why this happens?

Here's the build script using.  It's based off of [Unity3dBuilder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unity3dBuilder+Plugin) example code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class OmiyaGamesBuildScript
{
    private static readonly string[] AllScenes = FindEnabledEditorScenes();
    private const BuildOptions Options = BuildOptions.None;
    private const string BuildDirectory = "Builds";

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build All")]
    public static void BuildAllPlatforms()
    {
        PerformWebBuild();
        PerformWindows32Build();
        PerformWindows64Build();
        PerformMac32Build();
        PerformMac64Build();
        PerformLinux32Build();
        PerformLinux64Build();

        //PerformIosBuild();
        //PerformAndroidBuild();
        //PerformWp8Build();
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Web")]
    public static void PerformWebBuild()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Web\\" + PlayerSettings.productName, BuildTarget.WebPlayer);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Windows 32")]
    public static void PerformWindows32Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Windows 32-bit\\" + PlayerSettings.productName + ".exe", BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Windows 64")]
    public static void PerformWindows64Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Windows 64-bit\\" + PlayerSettings.productName + ".exe", BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Mac 32")]
    public static void PerformMac32Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Mac 32-bit\\" + PlayerSettings.productName + ".app", BuildTarget.StandaloneOSXIntel);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Mac 64")]
    public static void PerformMac64Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Mac 64-bit\\" + PlayerSettings.productName + ".app", BuildTarget.StandaloneOSXIntel64);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Linux 32")]
    public static void PerformLinux32Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Linux 32-bit\\" + PlayerSettings.productName, BuildTarget.StandaloneLinux);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Linux 64")]
    public static void PerformLinux64Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Linux 64-bit\\" + PlayerSettings.productName, BuildTarget.StandaloneLinux64);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build iOS")]
    public static void PerformIosBuild()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\iOS\\" + PlayerSettings.productName, BuildTarget.iPhone);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Android")]
    public static void PerformAndroidBuild()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Android\\" + PlayerSettings.productName, BuildTarget.Android);
    }

    [MenuItem ("Omiya Games/Build Windows 8")]
    public static void PerformWp8Build()
    {
        GenericBuild(BuildDirectory + "\\Windows 8\\" + PlayerSettings.productName, BuildTarget.WP8Player);
    }

    private static void GenericBuild(string targetDirectory, BuildTarget buildTarget)
    {
        EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(buildTarget);
        string res = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(AllScenes, targetDirectory, buildTarget, Options);
        if (res.Length > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to build to " + targetDirectory + ":\n" + res);
        }
    }

    private static string[] FindEnabledEditorScenes()
    {
        List<string> EditorScenes = new List<string>();
        foreach(EditorBuildSettingsScene scene in EditorBuildSettings.scenes)
        {
            if (scene.enabled == true)
            {
                EditorScenes.Add(scene.path);
            }
        }
        return EditorScenes.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the project's current build settings:

[image: Jenkins project settings screenshot]

Screenshot of Jenkins' settings:

[image: Jenkins system settings screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked your build script without Jenkins from a command-line?

Comment: Good question.  I have tested it on my laptop.  I figured it'd work just fine on my server, but it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around copying the command line printed in the output into the server, and discovered I made a typo.  Instead of `-bashmode`, I'm supposed to use `-batchmode`.  The full Unity argument now reads as follows:

```
-batchmode -quit -executeMethod OmiyaGamesBuildScript.BuildAllPlatforms
```

I also made a mistake above to run shell commands on a Windows Machine, so I switched that to batch commands.